# How to check if input in input field has alphabets only in express-validator

Tags: node.js, express-validator

I'm trying to give error if the input field i.e name not only consists of alphabets in express-validator

```
req.check('name')
     .isLength({min:3}).withMessage('Name must be of 3 characters long.')
     .isAlpha().withMessage('Name must be alphabetic.');
```

but when i enter "John Doe" in "name" input field it says "Name must be alphabetic" instead of successful validation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.isAlpha()` method description from validator.js documentation (express-validator is also a wrapper for validation functions of this module):

> check if the string contains only letters (a-zA-Z)

Your string `John Doe` contains a whitespace, that's why validation is not succesfull.

Your validation chain can be this one:

```
req.check('name')
   .isLength({min:3}).withMessage('Name must be of 3 characters long.')
   .matches(/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/).withMessage('Name must be alphabetic.')
```

`.isAlpha()` is replaced with `matches()`. Validation is successful when `name` is a string with 3 characters and more (alphabetic characters or whitespaces only).

Source: [validator.js validators](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#validators)

Comment: Thanks @HlibDerbenov it's working as i exprected . I just don't get the regex part. Would u like to explain me regex part ?i don't see inclusion of whitespace anywhere

Comment: @SurajOberai whitespace is included because of `\s` in regular expression. There's a really good website for building regular expressions: https://regexr.com

Comment: I got it ! Thank u so much @HlibDerbenov

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner, more complete and proper solution:

> File: routes/auth.route.js

```
const express = require('express');
const controller = require('../controllers/auth.controller');
const {body} = require('express-validator');

const router = express.Router();

// Validators Definition:
.
.
.
const registerValidators = [
    .
    .
    .
    body('firstName')
        .exists({checkFalsy: true}).withMessage('You must type a first name')
        .isLength({min: 3}).withMessage('The first name must be at least 5 chars long')
        .isAlpha('en-US', {ignore: '\s'}).withMessage('The first name must contain only letters'),
];

// Routes Definition:
.
.
.
router.post('/register', ...registerValidators, controller.register);

module.exports.routes = router;
```

You could also do it this way:

```
.isAlpha('es-ES', {ignore: ' '}).withMessage('The first name must contain only letters'),
```